# c# assembly.GetExportedTypes

Tags: c#, reflection, gettype

I am trying to get the type for the lowest class(`G`) in the chain of classes one inheriting from the other as shown below.

1.`public class G: F`

2.`public class F: E<STate>`

3.`public abstract class E<TState> : D<TState, StatusQueryParams> where TState : E, new()`

4.`public abstract class D<TState, TQuery> :C<TState, TQuery>`

5.`public abstract class C<TState, TQuery> : IA, IB`

6.`public interface IA: IB`

Additionally, I know only the type of `IA` all the rest is customer code which keep changing. So knowing the type of `IA` I should get type of `G`

Currently I am using:

```
var classtype= assembly.GetExportedTypes().Where(t =>
typeof(IA).IsAssignableFrom(t) && t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract);
```

This doesn't work for me for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
try using this i will help

    public class IA
    {
       public static void Main()
       {
          foreach (var t in typeof(IA).Assembly.GetTypes()) {
             Console.WriteLine("{0} derived from: ", t.FullName);
             var derived = t;
             do { 
                derived = derived.BaseType;
                if (derived != null) 
                   Console.WriteLine("   {0}", derived.FullName);

             } while (derived != null);
             Console.WriteLine(); 
          } enter code here
       }
```